# Try-Catch with do while loop

Tags: java

```
// Add a New Ship
public static void addShip() {
    // complete this method
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter new Ship name: "); // Ask for ship name
    String shipName = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Balcony: "); // How many Balcony suites
    int balcony = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Ocean View:"); // How many Ocean view suites
    int oceanView = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Room Suite: ");
    int roomSuite = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Room Interior: ");
    int roomInterior = scan.nextInt();
            
    **int y = 1;
    do {
        try {
            System.out.print("In Service: ");
            boolean inService = scan.nextBoolean(); // Ask if the ship is in service
            y=2;
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Please enter true if ship is in service.");
            System.out.println("or");
            System.out.print("False if ship is not in service");
        }
    } while (y==1);
    scan.nextLine();
    shipList.add(new Ship(shipName, balcony, oceanView, roomSuite, roomInterior, inService));   //this is the inService error I am referring to
}**
```

The bold is where I am having trouble (beginning at line 19 ending at 36). At first, I was trying to make my boolean I yes or no instead of true or false. When I couldn't figure that out I decided to do a try-catch to prompt the user to enter true or false.
Two things happened. 1st the "inService" variable in line 36 now says it couldn't be resolved. So I used the eclipse suggestion and created a field for 'inService'. When I ran the program and got to t that part the loop never stopped, I had to terminate the console manually.

I'm going to have to implement a try-catch for the rooms also to make sure the user doesn't input a string such as "three" instead of "3". I was going to use this same method but I can't get this one working.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please **edit** the question and fix the indentation of the code, so the code structure can be followed. Sorry, I personally refuse to attempt interpreting badly formatted code like that.

Comment: And please mention your errors as comments in the code as there are no line numbers to refer to in the code.

Comment: @Andreas well I'm still learning. I just started coding like a week ago.

Comment: Then @Andreas is helping you learn, about code formatting and why it's important (it improves code readability), since if you plan to ask future questions, you will want to strive to learn Java code format conventions and strive to post well-constructed code. What happens if you move the `scan.nextLine()` to the bottom of the try *and* have the same line at the bottom of the catch blocks?

Comment: @boobalan I just added it. It's the very last line of actual code. Not counting the curly brace at the end.

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter That worked. Is it because the `scan.nextLine()` was part of the original code before the try-catch

Comment: You're handing the end-of-line token regardless of whether the data submitted was correct or incorrect

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter I just noticed when I enter it correctly (true). It just keeps asking me "In Service" over and over like it's now on a loop.

Comment: @user13711113: it works for me. Please see my code in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your loop never stops is that you're setting y=2 after `scan.nextBoolean()`, so if that methods throw an exception the line with y=2 will be skipped and it will reach directly the catch block. So in this case you should set y=2 inside the catch block to make it work.

```
int y = 1;
do {
    try {
        System.out.print("In Service: ");
        boolean inService = scan.nextBoolean(); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        y = 2;
    }
} while (y==1);
```

However it'd be better if you use `scan.hasNextBoolean()` in the while condition, so that you can avoid using a try-catch

```
while (scan.hasNextBoolean()) {
    System.out.print("In Service: ");
    boolean inService = scan.nextBoolean(); 
}
```

Comment: I have to use a try-catch.

Comment: Why? You don't need it

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the Scanner's end of line token regardless of whether correct or incorrect input has been given, and so this means that you should swallow this token with `scan.nextLine()` at the end of both the try and the catch blocks. For instance:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean inputOk = false;
boolean inService = false;
do {        
    try {
        System.out.print("In Service: ");
        inService = scan.nextBoolean(); // Ask if the ship is in service
        inputOk = true;
        scan.nextLine();  // ***** add this here ***** 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: bad input. Enter either true or false");
        scan.nextLine();  // *****  add this here ***** 
    }

} while (!inputOk);

System.out.println("inService: " + inService);

if (scan != null) {
    scan.close();
}
```

Note also that I used a descriptive boolean variable to control the do-while loop since it avoids use of "magic numbers", 1 and 2, makes the code self-commenting and the logic easier to understand.